# Drupal 7 Views Organic Groups Complex Relationship

Tags: views, organic-groups, entities

I have an Organic Groups setup with many relationships. My groups are separated into 3 primary group types..let's call them:

- Trucks
- Cars
- Vans

All of these groups have group content:

- Tires
- Rims

I've created a view that is a list of Tires and I need to be able to sort by group type...so I need a list of tires for Trucks (for instance). How do I relate the bundle type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me....

Create two relationship:

- OG membership from node
- Group node from OG membership (Relate to
  Above)

Filter by Content Type and use relationship Group node from OG membership.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me too. I was looking for a way to show the node types of a connected group!